# Fixing router link color not working when active

Tags: html, css, angular

So, I was doing some menu bar codes for a website I needed, and RouterLinkActive's CSS color styling weren't working...

HTML:

```
  <ul class="nav" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
<li style="display: inline;" [routerLinkActive]="'active'"><a [routerLink]="['home']" routerLinkActive="active">HOME</a></li>
<li style="display: inline;"><a routerLink="/blog">BLOG</a></li>
<li style="display: inline;"><a routerLink="/contact-us">CONTACT US</a></li>
<li style="display: inline;"><a routerLink="/login">LOGIN</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
`nav a {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #42545C;
}
nav a.active {
  background-color: black;
}
div { text-align: center; }
/* Navi-bar */
ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 14px 28px;
margin: 0;
text-align: right;
}
ul.nav {
  padding-left: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
ul.nav > li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
ul.nav > li > a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active{
  color:#C32F4B;
} 
`
```

Does anyone have an idea to fix the code? My purpouse is to make the HOME part have the color forever,even if after hovered.

Comment: You should add the directive `[routerLinkActive]="'active'"` in **all** the `<a>`. NOTE: Use [RouterLinkActiveOption](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description) `{exact: true}` if it's neccesary. This directive add the class "active" to the tag where is applied -can be add not only to `<a>`- when the path matchs

Comment: For me,it doesn't work somehow and i tried all the solutions on the internet...

Comment: it's related to another question, but in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dg5zhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) you can see a nav with active. If you replace the app.component.css with your code looks like work. Check if you has another .css that override your .css